# How do I override the price for a widget price filter?

Tags: php, wordpress

Tell me please what hook (or not hook) the widget price filter is overridden by the price from the custom field?
For orderby **(woocommerce-ordering)** did as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_price_args' );

function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_price_args( $args ) {


$orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters('woocommerce_get_price', 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

if ( 'price_list' == $orderby_value ) {

$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
$args['order'] = 'ASC';
$args['meta_key'] = 'rrp_price';
return $args;

} elseif ( 'price_list2' == $orderby_value ) {

$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
$args['order'] = 'DESC';
$args['meta_key'] = 'rrp_price';
return $args;
}
}
```

Where **'rrp_price'** - name of cutom field.